# openssl pkcs12 -export return me error as unable to load certificates

Tags: ruby, push-notification, openssl, apple-push-notifications

Till date I used to follow below steps to create p12 file for push.

```
openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform DER -out aps_development_identity.pem -outform PEM}
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out private_development_key.pem -in Certificates.p12
openssl rsa -out private_key_noenc.pem -in private_development_key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_development_identity.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem -certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -name "aps_development_identity" -out aps_development_identity.p12
```

Note : I already have `aps_development.cer`, `Certificates.p12`, `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` in my folder.

However today I got error on executing last statement in terminal.

After executing last sentence, I get error as below.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_development_identity.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem -certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -name "aps_development_identity" -out aps_development_identity.p12

unable to load certificates --> this is what I get in response
```

Till now I didn't get any error like this.

***Any idea what I am missing.***

---

I just figured that this is happening due to I update the Ruby for pods.

Any there anything updated in Ruby for this export?

Comment: The [swift] tag is for questions about the Swift programming language, not to “attract Swift/iOS developers.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_development_identity.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem -name "aps_development_identity" -out aps_development_identity.p12
```

Just remove `-certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` from last statement & you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because there were spaces in my cer file which I copied and pasted from a website. When I retried with a file with no spaces it worked.